# How to display request payload value in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, http-post, payload

One of our angular2 application is posting some data to an aspx page (using HTTPPOST). I could see the posted values under Network in Developer Tools (in browser).

I just wanted to pass that value to another webservice or to display in the page body itself.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = Request.InputStream;
// Find number of bytes in stream.
strLen = Convert.ToInt32(str.Length);
// Create a byte array.
byte[] strArr = new byte[strLen];
// Read stream into byte array.
strRead = str.Read(strArr, 0, strLen);

// Convert byte array to a text string.
strmContents = "";
for (counter = 0; counter < strLen; counter++)
{
    strmContents = strmContents + strArr[counter].ToString();            
}
```

Comment: This just displaying the length of that string. I wanted to read the actual data

Comment: Yeah i checked that. Its returning the length of that data string

Comment: @Sam1604 Sorry for not reading the question correctly, now verify.

Comment: It's displaying numbers like 9032323210... I wanted to see the actual string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155915/discussion-between-sam1604-and-ipsit-gaur).

Comment: strArr[counter].ToString() --> have converted this to Char. That works for me. Appreciate your help on time